# changing the <fieldset> colour dependant on an If statement

Tags: php, html, css, if-statement, fieldset

firstly sorry if this is a stupid question but her goes....
I am trying create a change of colour based on a $_session variable like this

```
<li>             
  <fieldset>
    <?php

    if ($_SESSION['Question1Answer'] != '1C') {
        <?php fieldset id="incorrect" />
        echo "Q1. When was barb wire patented.";
        echo "The Correct answer is 1874";
    }
        <?php fieldset id="correct" />
    ?>
  </fieldset>                   
</li>
```

then in the style sheet I have

```
#incorrect {
    color: red;
    border: medium;
}
#correct {
    color: green;
    border: thin;
}
```

Does any one know what I am doing wrong please ?

Comment: Sorry for some reason the start line item and start fieldset are missing from above in this post but they are there !

Comment: `<?php fieldset id="incorrect" />` – that is not valid PHP code. You need to go learn the basics. http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.php

Comment: You need to check if the answer is correct BEFORE you output your `<fieldset>`, then apply the class to that fieldset: `<fieldset class="<?php echo $fieldsetClass ?>">`

Comment: seems to me that you should be using a class as well, in stead of an ID

Comment: @CBroe, as you say I was not sure that the code was right I could not find (using google somewhere were the syntax was explained so thanks for the url I will check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the answer is correct BEFORE you output your `<fieldset>`, then apply the id to that fieldset:

```
<?php
if ($answer == "correct") {
  $fieldsetID = "correct";
} else {
  $fieldsetID = "incorrect";
}
?>
<li>
  <fieldset id="<?php echo $fieldsetID ?>">
  </fieldset>                   
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks so  much for your answer I can see what you are saying and how it works. As I said in the question I am still a beginner and I find this answer very helpful.